# Install programm such as MongoDB on another drive than the c one

Tags: mongodb, windows, installation, storage

On my Windows 11 computer, I have very limited storage capacity on the C-Drive but 1TB of space on my D-Drive.
I recently installed MongoDB, which didn't give me the option to install it on D but by its own will installed itself on C.
I have found a folder in
C:\Users\imelf\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass and C:\Users\imelf\AppData\Local\mongodb and C:\Programme\MongoDB

Would it work to simply copy all these folders manually to D:\Software and delete all the other files on the C-Drive ? Can I then expect MongoDBCompass\MongoDBCompass.exe to still work?

Or what would you have to be aware of doing this? I wonder also what this AppData\Local folder is? Many programs seem to use this folder.

Comment: You may empty your trashbin

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some programs are installed in `C:\Users\imelf\AppData\Local` (or simply `%LOCALAPPDATA%`) because it does not require Administrator privileges to install programs there - it is a personal folder of your user account. Typically this folder also contains user settings/personalization which you do in your applications, you should not delete or move it. In principle you could re-define variable `LOCALAPPDATA` but I don't recommend this, most likely you will break at least some applications.

However, usually it is no big issue to delete the content of your `%TEMP%` folder `C:\Users\imelf\AppData\Local\Temp`. As the name implies, this folder holds only temporary data which is not needed persistently.

The `mongod.exe` is a single binary of only 50 MByte, it should be no problem to put it to your c-drive. And Mongo Compass or the `mongosh.exe` are also rather small. You can put these binaries wherever you like.

For location of the data, you also have free choice.

I suggest to create a configuration file like this:

```
storage:
  dbPath: D:\MongoDB\data

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  D:\MongoDB\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost

processManagement:
  windowsService:
    serviceName: MongoDB
    displayName: MongoDB
    description: MongoDB Server - Standalone DB
```

Then you can install the service with

```
mongod.exe --config "<full path of your config file>" --install
```

Then the MongoDB will start automatically when you boot your PC. Note, you have to install the service with Administrator privileges and you must create the folders for data and logs beforehand.

Another note, if you really dare to change the location of your home folder see https://www.windowscentral.com/how-move-default-user-folders-new-drive-windows-10 or https://superuser.com/questions/1190364/how-to-set-home-directory-in-win10

**Update**

You can got to "This PC" -> Manage -> Services and Applications. There you can start/stop or disable the MongoDB service. If you like to remove the service entirely use

```
mongod.exe --config "<full path of your config file>" --remove
```

In case, the config file is not available anymore use these commands:

```
sc config MongoDB start=disabled
sc delete MongoDB
```

Comment: Great! How would it be possible to uninstall the service again? Because I don't want it to be permanently running.